# Move folder using spacemacs with emacs command

Tags: dired, spacemacs, m-x

I am a beginner using spacemacs and also new to emacs.
What I try is to use the command `M-x R new RET` (dired-do-rename).
Though everytime I type `M-x`, which is the same as `SPC :` I end up with helm-M-x. My problem is that I would like to use just the letter `R` now instead of typing e.g. `renam` to get the dired-do-rename command.
Is there a possibility to avoid helm-M-x when I know the shortcut (`M-x R new RET`in this case)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`M-x R new RET` is not the correct shortcut. `M-x`  (and `SPC :`) is for invoking a command by it's **name**, for example:

```
M-x dired-do-rename RET new-name RET
```

In Dired mode, `dired-do-rename` is bound to `R`, so you just need to type `R` **without `M-x`**, for example:

```
R new-name RET
```